# How to choose LUKS encryption when installing RHEL 6?

Tags: rhel, system-installation, luks

With the default RHEL 6 installer, how can I choose the LUKS encryption?

Afaik if I prepare the disk like

```
cryptsetup luksFormat -c cast5-cbc-plain -s 128 /dev/$DEVICE
```

could be the "fastest" encryption, but the installer only prompts for password, then later, at the partitioning it recognizes it as "unknown" partition.

UPDATE: so in short, I just want to speed up io with using the mentioned faster encryption (? are there faster/but still ""secure""?) with the default install. How can I don it?

**UPDATE#2: what would be the fastest encryption that can be still used in the default GUI install??**

Comment: I assume you mean RHEL 6? Redhat 6 was a circa 2001 release. I don't think LUKS existed back then.

Comment: I'm talking about the newest 6.3 RHEL. ex.: Scientific Linux 6.3

Comment: In case you are running this on recent hardware with AES-NI feature on your CPU, you should stick with AES - on common Intel Core processors this is offloaded and will reach 500+ MB/s easily.

Comment: no, cpu doesn't has aes-ni :\

Comment: Some reason you're using plain instead of essiv or *-xts? And cast5 instead of AES? Did you actually benchmark it to be faster, other benchmarks I find say AES should be faster than CAST5, even w/o AES-NI instructions.

Comment: I just googled the fastest encryption that is available in LUKS. Do you know better? I will use a very long password... more then 30 chars and I don't want to be secure against the CIA.. only regular burglars that maybe know how to use a bruteforce tool..

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-LUKS_Disk_Encryption.html                                      Have you took a look at Red Hat site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be stuck using a [kickstart to define the partition with the encryption type](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html#id983010) instead of using the graphical install interface.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you just tell it to format the 'unknown' partition that it will format it and leave the encryption just as you specified. So the strategy of using `luksFormat` to create a partition that uses a particular encryption scheme that you think will be faster will work.